# How to do img validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

how do i do image validation. the goal of this page is to make a simple game. this game requires some form of validation, however i can't seem to make the validation. my restriction on making is that i am only allowed to use CSS and Javascript.

So for example right now, my code is working where all images can go into any albums. Is it possible to make a validation where only specific images can go into specific albums. For example, i want only my first 4 images only to be able to go into the first album(north). and if other images try to be dragged into that album it will reject it and go back to its original spot.

```js
// add event handler
var addEvent = (function () {
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    return function (el, type, fn) {
      if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
        el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
      } else if (el && el.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
        }
      }
    };
  } else {
    return function (el, type, fn) {
      if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + type, function () { return fn.call(el, window.event); });
      } else if (el && el.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
        }
      }
    };
  }
})();

// inner variables
var dragItems;
updateDataTransfer();
var dropAreas = document.querySelectorAll('[droppable=true]');

// preventDefault (stops the browser from redirecting off to the text)
function cancel(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return false;
}

// update event handlers
function updateDataTransfer() {
    dragItems = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable=true]');
    for (var i = 0; i < dragItems.length; i++) {
        addEvent(dragItems[i], 'dragstart', function (event) {
            event.dataTransfer.setData('obj_id', this.id);
            return false;
        });
    }
}

// dragover event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'dragover', function (event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    // little customization
    this.style.borderColor = "#000";
    return false;
});

// dragleave event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'dragleave', function (event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    // little customization
    this.style.borderColor = "#ccc";
    return false;
});

// dragenter event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'dragenter', cancel);

// drop event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'drop', function (event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    // get dropped object
    var iObj = event.dataTransfer.getData('obj_id');
    var oldObj = document.getElementById(iObj);

    // get its image src
    var oldSrc = oldObj.childNodes[0].src;
    oldObj.className += 'hidden';

    var oldThis = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        oldObj.parentNode.removeChild(oldObj); // remove object from DOM

        // add similar object in another place
        oldThis.innerHTML += '<a id="'+iObj+'" draggable="true"><img src="'+oldSrc+'" /></a>';

        // and update event handlers
        updateDataTransfer();

        // little customization
        oldThis.style.borderColor = "#ccc";
    }, 500);

    return false;
});
```

```css
/* Page layout styles */
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    background-color:#fff;
    font:14px/1.3 Arial,sans-serif;
}
header {
    background-color:#212121;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px #111111;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    height:70px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}
header h2{
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px;
    padding: 25px 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 540px;
}
 margin-left:5px;
}

/* Photo Gallery styles */
.gallery {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    width: 840px;
}
.gallery a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 135px;
    margin: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;

    -khtml-user-drag: element;

    /* CSS3 Prevent selections */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.gallery a img {
    border: 8px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

    /* CSS3 Box sizing property */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;

    /* CSS3 Box Shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
}

/* Custom CSS3 rotate transformation */
.gallery a:nth-child(1) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-25deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(2) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(3) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(4) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(5) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(6) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(7) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(8) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(9) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform: rotate(15deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(10) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(11) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(25deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
    transform: rotate(25deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(12) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.gallery a:hover img {
    z-index: 5;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;

    /* CSS3 transform rules */
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.gallery a.hidden {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.albums {
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 840px;
}
.album {
    border: 3px dashed #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 220px;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    transition: all 1.0s ease;
}
.album a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 56px;
    margin: 15px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 75px;

    -khtml-user-drag: element;
    -webkit-user-drag: element;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;

    /* CSS3 Prevent selections */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.album a img {
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

    /* CSS3 Box sizing property */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;

    /* CSS3 Box Shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
}
```

```html
 <div class="albums">
            <div class="album" id="drop_1" droppable="true"><h2>North</h2></div>
            <div class="album" id="drop_2" droppable="true"><h2>Centre</h2></div>
            <div class="album" id="drop_3" droppable="true"><h2>South<h2></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a id="1" draggable="true"><img src="images/1.jpg"></a>
            <a id="2" draggable="true"><img src="images/2.jpg"></a>
            <a id="3" draggable="true"><img src="images/3.jpg"></a>
            <a id="4" draggable="true"><img src="images/4.jpg"></a>
            <a id="5" draggable="true"><img src="images/5.jpg"></a>
            <a id="6" draggable="true"><img src="images/6.jpg"></a>
            <a id="7" draggable="true"><img src="images/7.jpg"></a>
            <a id="8" draggable="true"><img src="images/8.jpg"></a>
            <a id="9" draggable="true"><img src="images/9.jpg"></a>
            <a id="10" draggable="true"><img src="images/10.jpg"></a>
            <a id="11" draggable="true"><img src="images/11.jpg"></a>
            <a id="12" draggable="true"><img src="images/12.jpg"></a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both access to the dragged objects id and the targets id. Which you can use for your validation. Here is an example which would allow the first 4 images to be in the first album, the next  in the second album, etc.

```
// drop event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'drop', function (event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    // get dropped object
    var iObj = event.dataTransfer.getData('obj_id');
    var oldObj = document.getElementById(iObj);

    // validate
    var target = "drop_" + Math.ceil(iObj/4); // first  images
    if(this.id !== target) {
        return false;
    }

    ...
});
```

Of course you can validate this in any way you want. You could also do something like:

```
<a id="1" draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_1"><img src="images/1.jpg"></a>
```

And validate it like this:

```
    var oldObj = document.getElementById(iObj);

    // validate
    if(this.id !== oldObj.dataset.dropTo) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thx alot for the help, the validation worked! but is there a way to maybe prompt a message when the last picture is droped into the album

Comment: You could just increase a counter everytime a picture is successfully dropped and if the counter equals the amount of pictures, then show the prompt.